# In python, why 'is' is preferred over '==' for checking if object in None

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison, pycharm, nonetype

If I write this:

```
if x == None:
    x = 1
```

My pyCharm editor keeps suggesting that I should use 'is' instead of '==':

```
if x is None:
    x = 1
```

For any other equality check pyCharm does not suggest the use of 'is', like:

```
if x == 2:
    x = 1
```

Why is the `'is'` operator preferred over the `'=='` operator while checking if object is `None`?

Why is it preferred only for `None`?

Comment: Note that you often see `if x:` used where `if x is not None:` should be, which can lead to problems with other false-y values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `None` is a singleton, there is only ever **one** copy of the object in a Python program.

`is` is faster when testing against a single object, because only the pointers need to be equal. `==` tests for more information, the *state of the objects tested* needs to be the same too in that case.

This becomes more pronounced still if your `x` object implements a custom [`object.__eq__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__); it'll be called each time you use `x == None`, while `x is None` doesn't have such a hook. That means the interpreter has to execute some more Python code each time you do an equality test. Did I mention already that a simple pointer equality test (used for `is`) is fast?

That hook also makes it possible for a custom type to declare itself equal to `None`:

```
class Devious(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other is None
```

Now your `x == None` test will be true even though `x` is not actually `None`, but an instance of `Devious` instead. If you really wanted to know if `x` was set to `None`, only `x is None` will be able to detect that case.

`None` is not the only object you can test for identity with. Any time you need to know if a given name is referencing a *specific object* rather than a *value*, you should use `is`.

For example, sometimes you need to allow for `None` to be a valid value, but you want to detect if *no value* has been specified. Normally you could use `None` as a sentinel to detect if an argument has been left out:

```
def foo(arg1, optional=None):
    if optional is None:
        # no value given for optional
```

but if you want `None` to be a valid value, you'd use a *different sentinel*:

```
_sentinel = object()

def foo(arg1, optional=_sentinel):
    if optional is _sentinel:
        # no value given for optional
```

Now you can use `foo(1, None)` and it'll be correctly treated as a value.

Comment: Additionally, `is` checks identity and cannot be overridden, while `==` and `!=` are operators that can be overloaded using `__eq__()` and `__ne__()`.